# implementing evaluate(XPath) in msxml

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm writing an experiment where I take an XML file, that has XPaths embedded in it, and try to process it against another XML file with data in it, where the XPaths refer to elements within some predefined nodeset inside the data....basically binding a view to a list of data.

I've basically got it working, except how to evaluate the XPaths themselves, clearly I can do it in saxon with 3.0 (maybe I should try there first), but it would be initially convenient if this worked in msxml. I've read stuff about "extensions" and embedding javascript...but I can't really see how it would work (it didnt work for me).

any ideas?

(I could make the xslt create an xslt that creates the output, but this is a rough and ready proof of concept, and that might make my head hurt).

I can if necessary create an explicit example, but my actual scenario is quite convoluted.

Comment: Why the tags for XSLT 2 and 3 while asking about MSXML? Microsoft has never supported those versions. And if you have code that failed then show us that attempt and how it failed, then perhaps it becomes clear what you are trying to achieve and of course which version of MSXML (old COM based MSXML 3 or 6?) or one of the two .NET processors (XslCompiledTransform?) you are trying to use.

Comment: I've removed the tags, apologies. I'll have to construct a short example, the version of MSXML...I'm not sure!...the one that gets executed using visual studio.

Comment: In the context of .NET and XslCompiledTransform, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvp.Xml.NetStandard and https://github.com/keimpema/Mvp.Xml.NetStandard/blob/master/library/Mvp.Xml/Exslt/GDNDynamic.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within .NET `XPathNavigator` has an `Evaluate` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.evaluate?view=netcore-3.1. You can expose it from an [extension object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-extension-objects) to XslCompiledTransform.

The Mvp.Xml library does this to expose a `dyn2:evaluate` extension function in the namespace `xmlns:dyn2="http://gotdotnet.com/exslt/dynamic"` to its wrapper `MvpXslTransform` class around `XslCompiledTransform`.

The library is available on NuGet in a .NET standard 2.0 compatible (i.e. both .NET framework and .NET Core compatible) package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mvp.Xml.NetStandard.

Simplest code would be (`using Mvp.Xml.Common.Xsl;`):

```
        var processor = new MvpXslTransform();

        processor.SupportedFunctions = Mvp.Xml.Exslt.ExsltFunctionNamespace.GdnDynamic;

        processor.Load("XSLTFile1.xslt");

        processor.Transform(new XmlInput("XMLFile1.xml"), null, new XmlOutput(Console.Out));
```

where the stylesheet uses e.g. `dyn2:evaluate(., path)` with `xmlns:dyn2="http://gotdotnet.com/exslt/dynamic"` where the `path` child element of the context node contains an XPath expression.

The source code is at https://github.com/keimpema/Mvp.Xml.NetStandard/blob/master/library/Mvp.Xml/Exslt/GDNDynamic.cs.

In the .NET framework you can also embed .NET code directly in the XSLT and `XslCompiledTransform` will compile and run it with the proper `XsltSettings` (`new XsltSettings() { EnableScript = true }`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:my-ext="http://example.com/my-ext"
   exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my-ext">

  <msxsl:script implements-prefix="my-ext" language="C#">
    public object evaluate(XPathNodeIterator context, string expression)
    {
    if (context.MoveNext()) {
      return context.Current.Evaluate(expression);
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
    }
  </msxsl:script>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xpath-test">
    <xsl:copy>
      <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="my-ext:evaluate(., path)"/>
      </result>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I don't know whether Visual Studio allows you to enable that setting for its transformation menu.

Comment: ok, so to do this I have to be in control of the XSLT transformer via the API? i.e. if I'm writing an XSLT for a 3rd party controlled MS XSLT engine, then that probably isnt enabled? The litmus test would be, if I run the XSLT in visual studio would I have access to this? (I'll try)

Comment: It is not clear what you refer to with "run the XSLT in visual studio", for me that would mean using Visual Studio to write and execute .NET code like shown. If you use a menu/feature of Visual Studio add a tag for it and explain what you are looking for, I don't know whether the commercial editions allow you to set up extension objects for XSLT, the community edition in my view does not even have that feature.

Comment: And https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/script-blocks-using-msxsl-script should probably allow you to embed the C# code calling the `Evaluate` method directly in the XSLT and have `XslCompiledTransform` compile it, all subject to security restrictions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not being clear. I don't control the execution of the XSLT, so the setup is analogous to going into visual studio, writing some XSLT and executing it (without setting any advanced options), so whats not clear to me is can I embed C# in such a scenario (actually when I've tried its not worked)

Comment: As I said, if the question is about a particular Visual Studio feature, ask Microsoft support or tag your question for Visual Studio and explain which version and edition you use, perhaps someone can tell you more. And "its not worked" is also not a very clear description as to which result or error message you get, as well as saying I have tried code but I don't show it doesn't enable anyone to fix the code or tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think I'm going to close the question and do it in Saxon....I was hoping it was a pretty standard..."if you want to emulate evaluate in the 'standard' vanilla ms XSLT engine, then you do X"...but I get the feeling it can be done, but only if something "clever" is happening

Comment: actually..this DOES work in visual studio....hmmmm....let me see if it works inside the production environment